# Finding the latest date in XmlNode using string[]

Tags: c#, arrays, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

I am looping through an `XmlNodeList` and getting the date of the nodes creation in a string[]. For example:

```
date[0] = 2016 //year
date[1] = 07 //month
date[2] = 23 //day
```

My question is, what would be the most efficient way of comparing this `string[]` to another `string[]`, to find the which one has the latest date? I could do it with a bunch of if statements comparing each element to one another, but feel that isn't the best/prettiest solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ParseExact` to create a `DateTime` out of the `string[]`. Then order by it:

```
List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>
{ 
    new string[] { "2016", "07", "23" }, 
    new string[] { "2017", "01", "01" } 
};

var latestTime = data.OrderByDescending(item => 
                         DateTime.ParseExact(string.Join("/", item), @"yyyy/MM/dd", null))
                     .FirstOrDefault();

//latestTime = 1/1/2017
```